# Python struct not working under Linux. Encoding?

Tags: python, linux, struct

I coded a client-server for windows which sends chars from one to another  using struct.pack/unpack.encoding('ascii'). I wanted to see if it works properly in ubuntu too and when I checked I got an error that it couldn't unpack my data, not even integers.

The error is here, in the server, when I try to receive and unpack the data

```
nr1 = c.recv(4096)
nr1 = struct.unpack('!i',nr1)[0]
```

it says that it requires a string argument of 4 bytes but I'm sending an int... After some research, I understood that it must be something related to encoding but nothing else. Any ideas why it's not working?

Here is the part where I send ( from the client ) the int:

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
nra = len(a)
c.send(struct.pack('!i',nra))
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: `unpack` goes from a string to an integer (or whatever else your format string specifies). Perhaps you want `struct.pack()` instead, if your input is an integer and you want a string?

Comment: ...that said, `recv()` most certainly does return a string, so I suspect that where you say you're "sending an int" that this is simply mistaken.

Comment: ...anyhow, look at the *actual* content of `nr1` before the point. Is it too short (so you need to `recv()` again to get more content)? Is it too long (so that it no longer meets the format string's specifier)? If instead of `nr1 = c.recv(4096)` you included `nr1='...an actual string here...'`, then folks could reproduce your error without needing a socket that's receiving the data you can see but nobody else can.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve, particularly the "complete" and "verifiable" aspects.

Comment: I send the data from the client to the server. I edited my post and put some client code too. The error is when I try receive from the client, inside the server. I mention again, this code works in windows. It just doesn't work in Linux (Ubuntu)

Comment: And that it doesn't work in Linux doesn't tell us anything useful. Maybe the way the TCP stack is coalescing received contents works a little differently. Maybe there's less latency before the `recv()` call returns, so more or less data is actually received when the syscall exits.

Comment: ...if you want a useful answer, you need to actually `print repr(nr1)` and put it in the question; otherwise, **even having your server code**, there's no guarantee that anyone else's system will behave identically.

Comment: I already told you what to give us: Put a line `print repr(nr1)` in your code, after the `recv()` call and before the `unpack()`, and add the results of that print to your question.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: ...because no, there **isn't** a difference between using `struct` across platforms unless you're telling it to use native byte order; **since you're specifying network byte order, `struct` is going to behave identically, so the question is whether `recv()` is behaving differently.**

Comment: I added a photo after printing what I get from recv and the error

Comment: There's a reason I asked you to print `repr()` results, not the literal string; as currently given in the screen shot, it's not readable.

Comment: ...however, even what's given there, I have a strong suspicion: You received more than one integer, so you have a string that's longer than 4 bytes.

Comment: I added a pic after print repr(nr1) too. Same result

Comment: That picture is very helpful -- it makes it entirely, unambiguously clear that your content received is more than four bytes. (In the future, by the way, consider copy-and-pasting such content as text rather than linking to images).

Comment: I couldn't copy from terminal characters like that. At least not from my knowledge. I know prints are not welcomed here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're unpacking a 4-byte integer, you should only receive 4 bytes:

```
nr1 = c.recv(struct.calcsize('!i'))
nr1 = struct.unpack('!i',nr1)[0]
```

Presumably, on your Windows system, only a 4-byte packet is received by the time the syscall returns; Linux would appear to have more data ready at that time.

If you want to receive a larger set of content but only unpack the first four bytes, that too is possible:

```
nr1 = c.recv(4096)
nr1 = struct.unpack('!i', nr1[:struct.calcsize('!i')])[0]
```

Comment: Ok you are right. After I changed everywhere in the code the numbers inside the recv with the correct expected nr of bytes, everything works perfectly. Thank you very much